# How to read my email in a threaded view?

Tags: email

I am subscribed to quite a few newslists for which the flat view is subpar in terms of readability and clarity.

Hence I am looking for a way to read them in a tree view mode like the desktop application Thunderbird does.

I have tried the standard Google Mail reader and K9 Mail unsuccessfully.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "Find me an app that does X" questions are generally not on-topic here. (Please review the [FAQ].)

Comment: See: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/353/are-questions-looking-for-apps-on-topic-as-in-i-need-an-app-that-does-xyz-o and the [FAQ#questions].

Comment: I think the underlying question here could have some potential, albeit with some work. Presented as "How can I view my emails in a threaded format?" this would be okay with a bit of additional information (such as what email client you're currently using, which ones you've tried that are insufficient, etc; basically a little legwork so it isn't just a weakly bounded app hunt).

Comment: @eldarerathis In the end it still would be asking for an app. It would be asking for an app just without explicitly saying that I ask for an app. Kind of absurd.

Comment: @k0pernikus You never know if there isn't a non app solution for the problem you are trying to solve. So asking for an app that does X is not the same as asking how can I solve X. Edit your question and it well be reopened eventually.